# db lock issue need to find the root cause

Tags: mysql, query-performance, query

I have database locks. when I checked the process list the time taken for insert and update query was too large may I knw why and what is the root caused? what should I do inorder to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Sounds like a missing clustered index.  Please show us `CREATE TABE` and the query.

Comment: hello sir, am working on mysql may be indexes only am not sure how can i send files to you please let me know I will share the details. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

There maybe many reasons to cause lock.
you can paste the result of "show processlist" and "select * from information_schema.innodb_trx"  for furtur investigation